# Ionic - Open some URL into modal

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework

I'm not sure if this is even possible but, I have a button (Add event to calendar).

This button should let the user create an entry to his Google calendar.

For this, I have to open somewhere this [URL](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit?text=My+Event&dates=20200512T230000Z/20200513T030000Z&details=blabla&location=Garage+Boston+-+20+Linden+Street+-+Allston,+MA+02134)

My concern here is that I don't want the user to "quit" the main page (where the button is placed). So opening it in a new tab is not an option.

So I'm wondering if it is possible to open it in ion-modal or anything else that keeps the user with the page.

Comment: Certainly you could. Just use an iframe. However, that is a complex page and is not going to be very pretty or functional inside of a small modal.

Answer (score 1):

If your app is based on `cordova` you can use [In App Browser](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-browser) to load a url within the app.

If you are using `capacitor` you can use [Browser Plugin](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/browser), same purpose.

Comment: Does in app browser make sense in Web application?

Comment: Cordova In App Browser will not work in a web application, because cordova does not support browsers.. On the other hand, Capacitor Browser plugin will work in a web application..